# Looking for Linux command line twitter client to send image and text in tweet

Tags: linux, images, command-line, twitter

I have a need to programatically generate status tweets along with a graphical picture in embedded linux using command line. I want to invoke the client using system() (C library) call and pass the tweet text and image filename in the common line string.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I created a Java SE version of my Android app [EmailTweetor](http://www.vsubhash.com/subhash-email-tweetor-app-for-android.html), which can be launched from command-line.

To tweet a message

```
java -jar EmailTweetor.jar tweet hello.txt
```

or

```
echo "Hello" | java -jar EmailTweetor.jar tweet
```

To tweet with an image:

```
java -jar EmailTweetor.jar tweet hello.txt image.jpg
```

[image: EmailTweetor for Desktop]

The computer where the command is launched will need to have OpenJDK or Oracle Java v1.8 or later. The JAR also needs a one-time authorization with Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at [twidge](https://jgoerzen.github.io/twidge/twidge-html/twidge.html).

twidge is a client for microblogging sites such as Twitter and Identica (identi.ca). Microblogging sites let you post short one-paragraph updates, follow the updates that your friends post, and interact with everyone in the site in a conversation style.